# "Escopo do programa não foi fechado corretamente." em pseudocódigo

Tags: portugol, pseudocódigo

Escrevi o seguinte pseudocódigo só que estou recebendo o seguinte erro: O escopo do programa não foi fechado corretamente. insira o caracter `'}'` para corrigir o problema. Já tentei fechar com o `'}'` só que acaba gerando mais erros, alguém poderia me ajudar?

```
programa
{ Var cont, somatoria: inteiro
    funcao inicio()
    { cont ← 0 
        para cont ← 1 Ate 100 Faca 
            soma ← soma + cont 
            cont ← cont + 1
        fim para
        escreva "A somatoria é: ", soma 
    }
}
```

Comment: Em que ferramenta isto está sendo escrito?

Comment: estou usando o Portugol Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que a sintaxe não corresponde ao portugol tradicional

```
programa
{   
    funcao inicio()
    {
        inteiro cont
        inteiro somatoria
        inteiro soma

        cont = 0
        somatoria = 0
        soma = 0

        para (cont = 1; cont < 10; cont++)
        {
               soma = soma + cont 
               cont = cont + 1
        }         
        escreva ("A somatoria é: ", soma)       
    }
}
```

*Site:* [**PortugolStudio**](http://univali-l2s.github.io/Portugol/)

Comment: ate o momento esta certo mais preciso fazer com que ele some no intervalo de 1 até 10 e tem que ser números inteiros.

Comment: Só lembrando que a soma já foi feita no exemplo!

Answer (score 6):

Você tem um `fim para` sobrando, apague ele

```
programa
{ 
    Var cont, somatoria: inteiro
    funcao inicio()
    { 
        cont ← 0 
        para cont ← 1 Ate 100 Faca 
           soma ← soma + cont 
           cont ← cont + 1
        fim para
        escreva "A somatoria é: ", soma
    }
    fim para //apague essa linha
    escreva "A somatoria é: ", soma //essa linha está repetida, seria isso proposital?
}
```

É sempre importante identar corretamente seu código, assim você evita esse tipo de erro bobo. Perceba o espaço que eu pus antes de cada linha tornando o código muito mais legível.

**EDIÇÃO**

Você escreveu seu programa em pseudo-código, entretanto o [Portugol](http://siaiacad17.univali.br/alice/portugolStudio/) possui uma sintaxe bem definida de programação, um exemplo correto de laço de repetição `for` seria:

```
para(inteiro i=0; i<qtd; i++) {
    escreva("i vale", i)
}
```

Dentre vários outros detalhes que você passou batido, como por exemplo a declaração de variáveis deveria ser:

```
inteiro cont, somatoria
```

Comment: eu tinha testado novamente e acabei esquecendo esta parte mais o erro não tem nada a ver com esta linha.

Comment: @matheusferreira você tem certeza disso? se sim, poderia então atualizar seu código e seu erro?

Comment: o erro esta na linha 2 . o mesmo erro que esta na edição.

Comment: não, eu já apaguei oque estava repetindo o erro esta em uma parte usando o { e esta falando que não esta fechando corretamente para fechar usar o } mais já tentei.

Comment: @matheusferreira estou baixando essa ferramenta

Comment: @matheusferreira a sitaxe dos comandos é completamente diferente do que você escreveu

Comment: poderia ser mais claro? meio que testei esse programa e estou pensando em testar em outro poderia me indicar um de confiança para escrever este código sem nem um tipo de erro?

Comment: @matheusferreira dá uma olhada nesse vídeo [aqui](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AKK8NPeeROM&index=7&list=PLb9yvNDCid3jQAEbNoPHtPR0SWwmRSM-t)

Comment: @matheusferreira por favor, veja minha **EDIÇÃO**

Answer (score 4):

Existe um fim para antes do ultimo escreva